# How to fix java:1: error: '{' expected

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to compile a simple class in Java but can't work out what the error means. I'm very new to Java.

The error is:

```
Book.java:1: error: '{' expected
public class Book(String bookName)
                 ^
```

code

```
public class Book(String bookName)
{

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public Book() 
    {
        name = bookName;
        Random r = new Random();
        int lowPrice = 10;
        int highPrice = 100;
        price = r.nextInt(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Java not Scala. The constructor goes inside the body, not at the declaration scope

Comment: Thank you. I've read through a book of it today, but just trying to get my head around it. Apologies if my ignorance offends. I was asking for help.

Comment: @elksie5000 with 1.1k reputation on StackOverflow, I would expect you to be familiar with pages such as [ask] and to know the text on the downvote button - "This question does not show any research effort (...)". You might find this page very useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: I've been attempted to down vote your question, but sometimes the mind is in 'pause/forever loop' mode. So, I ASK you not to delete this question - reputation doesn't matter at all. Let this be as an example for very yang people who's questions was multiply down voted in a part of the second...

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak, Please do not judge. We are all humans, and one of the human's attribute is to make mistakes.

Comment: @zlakad, I wasn't going to delete the question. I'm guessing that there might be others who face the same situation with their first day in a new language.

Comment: @elksie5000 Kudos to you.

Answer (score 5):

Your class is wrongly declared. You need to remove the `class` declarator from the declaration of the class constructor.

Your class declaration `public class Book(String bookName)` isn't allowed in java. You need to change it to `public class Book`

`Random#nextInt(...)` does not return a String it returns an int. Change `String price` to `int price`

Try this:

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private int price;

    public Book(String bookName) {
        name = bookName;
        Random r = new Random();
        int lowPrice = 10;
        int highPrice = 100;
        price = r.nextInt(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this

```
public class Book(String bookName)
{
```

should be

```
public class Book
{
```

or you have to create a separate parameterized constructor

```
public class Book
{

    private String name;
    private String price;
    public Book(String bookName){
        //.. code
        name = bookName;
    }

    public Book() 
    {
        //name = bookName;
        Random r = new Random();
        int lowPrice = 10;
        int highPrice = 100;
        price = r.nextInt(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: That default constructor does not have a parameter namded `bookName`

Comment: @smac89 `constructor overloading`

Comment: Still no `bookName` variable in scope

Comment: @smac89 totally agree , updated and thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's code. There is no default constructor. He meant to use the `Book(String bookName)` as the constructor, but got the syntax wrong. With your new code, the `name` member is now uninitialized

Comment: @smac89 yeah , if OP uses the default constructor and IDK that OP wants the default constructor or not so i just left it there with the solution

Comment: Hi both. In Python you could instantiate an object with certain attributes. I was trying to do something like that. As I say, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @elksie5000 yeah in python it's possible but in java, the constructors should be defined inside body of class, like a function without any return type, for certain attributes, overload the constructor ,as shown in asnwer

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Thank you. It was my first Java program. First day in the language.

Comment: @elksie5000 i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

This declaration of class :

```
public class Book(String bookName)
```

**Is not allowed in Java.**

Maybe you mean to create a constructor like this :

```
public class Book {

    //...

    public Book(String bookName) {
        this.name = bookName;
    }

    //...
}
```

---

**Other problems**

- `Random::nextInt` return an `int` not a `String`, so the declaration
  `private String price;` should be `private int price;`.
- You can use getter and setter as well

In the end I assume your code should look like this :

```
public class Book {

    private @Getter @Setter String name;
    private @Getter @Setter int price;

    public Book(String bookName) {
        this.name = bookName;
    }

    public Book() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int lowPrice = 10;
        int highPrice = 100;
        price = r.nextInt(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
    }

}
```

---

Take a look at this :

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Comment: My question to you: Whenever you instantiate the new Book, you're creating new Random r. Isn't is cheaper (and more elegant) to declare r as private static field?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @zlakad, In this answer I just fix the big problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Changed Class declaration and added Main method

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public Book(String bookName) 
    {
        this.name = bookName;
        Random r = new Random();
        int lowPrice = 10;
        int highPrice = 100;
        this.price = r.nextInt(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
    }

  public void printBookDetails(){
  System.out.println("The book "+this.name + "is for "+ this.price +"dollars");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
          Book book =new Book("MyBook");
          book.printBookDetails();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Book {

```
private String name;


 Book(String bookName) 
 {
   this.name = bookName;
}
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int price;
    int lowPrice = 10;
    int highPrice = 100;
    price =(highPrice - lowPrice) + lowPrice;
        System.out.println(price);
}
```

}